# Dispatch onBlur before send form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux

I have a form with an email that creates an account on the backend
and the user can change the email in this step. This code do this by putting the function in onBlur, **but if I change the email in the input and don't leave the field, onBlur doesn't happen.** I can click submit direct, sending my old email for account creation.

This is the code:

```
const SendForm = ({ submit }) => {

  const onLabelSubmit = () => async (event, newValue, name) => {
      handleLabelSubmit(newValue, name);
  };

  const submitForm = () => {
    // validations 
    submit();
  };

  const handleSubmitAccount = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(submitAccount(field.name, field.email))
      .then(() => {
        submitForm();
      });
  };


  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmitAccount}>
              <Field
                id="email"
                name="email"
                label="label"
                onBlur={onLabelSubmit(label.email)}
              />

            <Button type="submit">
              Submit Form
            </Button>
      </form>
  );
};
```

Is there any way to do what onBlur does, but when I click the submit button?
I need improving the experience and avoiding mistakes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add state to the component with `useState`.
Instead of `onBlur` use `onChange` and add `value` property to your input field, it will fire on every user input so you will always have the latest given email & username.

```js
const SendForm = ({ submit }) => {

  const [fields, setFields] = useState({ name: '', email: '' })

  const onFieldChange = () => async (newValue, name) => {
      setFields({ ...fields, [name]: newValue });
  };

  const submitForm = () => {
    // validations 
    submit();
  };

  const handleSubmitAccount = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(submitAccount(field.name, field.email))
      .then(() => {
        submitForm();
      });
  };


  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmitAccount}>
              <Field
                id="email"
                name="email"
                label="label"
                value={fields.email}
                onChange={onFieldChange(label.email)}
              />

            <Button type="submit">
              Submit Form
            </Button>
      </form>
  );
};
```